# Need Regular Expression for Phone Number in MVC Data Annotation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Need Regular expression for Phone Number like

```
(123)-123-1212  Valid 
(123)-123-121  InValid 
(123)-123-12   InValid
1212-344---    Invalid
(000)-123-1212  InValid
```

Only first format should be valid. Number should be `0-9`
I don't have any idea regarding this expression

Comment: Have you tried some regular expressions? What problems did you run into when you tried?

Comment: Are (001)-123-1212  (010)-123-1212  (100)-123-1212 valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
^\((?!000)\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` match start of the string
- `\(` followed by a parentheses `(` (escaped because it has special meaning in regex)
- `(?!000)` negative lookahead (to fail for `000`)
- `\d{3}` match a digit exactly three times (`\d` equivalent to `[0-9]`)
- `\)` close parentheses
- `-` match hyphen literally
- `\d{3}-\d{4}` followed by exactly 3 digits then a hyphen and exactly 4 digits
- `$` followed by end of the string (so that it wont match strings with other charcters after the specified patten)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer , But (000)-123-1212  InValid is not working.

Comment: @karthikmanchala I am not a down voter but I believe you need to explain a little bit so that a newbie like me gains a little bit understanding of regular expressions.

Comment: @BikalBhattarai added explanation.. :)